# how to change the content of specific label?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to change the content of a specific label. I now have this but it is not working.

```
<label for="product_configure_variants">Make a choice: <em>*</em></label>
```

..

```
<style>
label:before[for="product_configure_variants"]{content: "my new content"!important;}
</style>
```

Can anyone help please to get it working? To change "Make a choice:" into "my new content".

Comment: use javascript/jquery

Comment: @Ahefaz, how, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `font-size: 0` on label to hide its text and then again change font size of `em` and `before` pseudo-element to show them, also your selector was wrong.

```css
label[for="product_configure_variants"] {
  font-size: 0;
}
label[for="product_configure_variants"]:before {
  content: "my new content";
  font-size: 16px;
}
label em {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<label for="product_configure_variants">Make a choice: <em>*</em></label>
```

You can also use js and select contents of label and check if nodeType is 3 or text and if index is 0 and then remove it.

```js
$('label[for="product_configure_variants"]').contents().each(function(i) {
  if(i == 0 && this.nodeType == 3) $(this).remove()
})
```

```css
label[for="product_configure_variants"]:before {
  content: "my new content";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="product_configure_variants">Make a choice: <em>*</em></label>
```

Comment: thank you! One thing though, Now other labels are being hidden too. How do I first set font-size : 0 for only this one label?

Answer (score 1):

It can be done in the following ways:

> **Option 1:** Just add a class to the label and do as below:

**HTML:**

```
    <label for="product_configure_variants" class="my-label">Make a choice: <em>*</em></label>
```

**JS:**

```
    $('.my-label').text('My new Content');
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2691/oc1L6weL/)

> **Option 2:** Access via `label` and attribute `for`.

**HTML:**

```
<label for="product_configure_variants">Make a choice: <em>*</em></label>
```

**JS:**

```
$('label[for="product_configure_variants"]').text('My new Content');
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2691/nj05xLtz/)

Comment: This was a cleaner way of doing it using jQuery.